# Unable to run command rasa train

Tags: python-3.x, macos, rasa

I'm trying to install my first rasa project but when I run `rasa train` I get those error messages. can someone help me? (Sorry If is too messy its my first time in StackOverflow)

(venv) ➜  rasa-init-demo rasa train
The configuration for policies and pipeline was chosen automatically. It was written into the config file at 'config.yml'.
Training NLU model...
2021-02-08 18:38:15 INFO     rasa.shared.nlu.training_data.training_data  - Training data stats:
2021-02-08 18:38:15 INFO     rasa.shared.nlu.training_data.training_data  - Number of intent examples: 69 (7 distinct intents)

2021-02-08 18:38:15 INFO     rasa.shared.nlu.training_data.training_data  -   Found intents: 'deny', 'goodbye', 'mood_unhappy', 'affirm', 'greet', 'mood_great', 'bot_challenge'
2021-02-08 18:38:15 INFO     rasa.shared.nlu.training_data.training_data  - Number of response examples: 0 (0 distinct responses)
2021-02-08 18:38:15 INFO     rasa.shared.nlu.training_data.training_data  - Number of entity examples: 0 (0 distinct entities)
2021-02-08 18:38:15 INFO     rasa.nlu.model  - Starting to train component WhitespaceTokenizer
2021-02-08 18:38:15 INFO     rasa.nlu.model  - Finished training component.
2021-02-08 18:38:15 INFO     rasa.nlu.model  - Starting to train component RegexFeaturizer
2021-02-08 18:38:15 INFO     rasa.nlu.model  - Finished training component.
2021-02-08 18:38:15 INFO     rasa.nlu.model  - Starting to train component LexicalSyntacticFeaturizer
2021-02-08 18:38:15 INFO     rasa.nlu.model  - Finished training component.
2021-02-08 18:38:15 INFO     rasa.nlu.model  - Starting to train component CountVectorsFeaturizer
2021-02-08 18:38:15 INFO     rasa.nlu.featurizers.sparse_featurizer.count_vectors_featurizer  - 80 vocabulary slots consumed out of 1080 slots configured for text attribute.
2021-02-08 18:38:15 INFO     rasa.nlu.model  - Finished training component.
2021-02-08 18:38:15 INFO     rasa.nlu.model  - Starting to train component CountVectorsFeaturizer
2021-02-08 18:38:15 INFO     rasa.nlu.featurizers.sparse_featurizer.count_vectors_featurizer  - 697 vocabulary slots consumed out of 1697 slots configured for text attribute.
2021-02-08 18:38:15 INFO     rasa.nlu.model  - Finished training component.
2021-02-08 18:38:15 INFO     rasa.nlu.model  - Starting to train component DIETClassifier
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 584, in converted_call
converted_f = conversion.convert(target_entity, program_ctx)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/conversion.py", line 118, in convert
transformed, module, source_map = _TRANSPILER.transform_function(
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/pyct/transpiler.py", line 411, in transform_function
factory = self._transformed_factory(fn, caching_subkey, user_context,
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/pyct/transpiler.py", line 373, in _transformed_factory
nodes, ctx = self._transform_function(fn, user_context)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/pyct/transpiler.py", line 339, in _transform_function
node = self.transform_ast(node, context)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/conversion.py", line 69, in transform_ast
node = qual_names.resolve(node)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/pyct/qual_names.py", line 252, in resolve
return QnResolver().visit(node)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ast.py", line 371, in visit
return visitor(node)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ast.py", line 456, in generic_visit
new_node = self.visit(old_value)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ast.py", line 371, in visit
return visitor(node)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ast.py", line 447, in generic_visit
value = self.visit(value)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ast.py", line 371, in visit
return visitor(node)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/pyct/qual_names.py", line 217, in visit_Name
node = self.generic_visit(node)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ast.py", line 456, in generic_visit
new_node = self.visit(old_value)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ast.py", line 371, in visit
return visitor(node)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/pyct/qual_names.py", line 230, in visit_Subscript
node = self.generic_visit(node)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ast.py", line 456, in generic_visit
new_node = self.visit(old_value)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ast.py", line 371, in visit
return visitor(node)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ast.py", line 447, in generic_visit
value = self.visit(value)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ast.py", line 371, in visit
return visitor(node)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/pyct/qual_names.py", line 232, in visit_Subscript
if not isinstance(s, gast.Index):
AttributeError: module 'gast' has no attribute 'Index'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/rasa", line 8, in 
sys.exit(main())
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/**main**.py", line 116, in main
cmdline_arguments.func(cmdline_arguments)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/cli/train.py", line 58, in 
train_parser.set_defaults(func=lambda args: train(args, can_exit=True))
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/cli/train.py", line 90, in train
training_result = rasa.train(
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/train.py", line 94, in train
return rasa.utils.common.run_in_loop(
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/utils/common.py", line 308, in run_in_loop
result = loop.run_until_complete(f)
File "uvloop/loop.pyx", line 1456, in uvloop.loop.Loop.run_until_complete
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/train.py", line 163, in train_async
return await _train_async_internal(
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/train.py", line 342, in _train_async_internal
await _do_training(
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/train.py", line 388, in _do_training
model_path = await _train_nlu_with_validated_data(
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/train.py", line 811, in _train_nlu_with_validated_data
await rasa.nlu.train(
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/nlu/train.py", line 116, in train
interpreter = trainer.train(training_data, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/nlu/model.py", line 209, in train
updates = component.train(working_data, self.config, **context)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/nlu/classifiers/diet_classifier.py", line 816, in train
self.model.fit(
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/utils/tensorflow/models.py", line 220, in fit
) = self._get_tf_train_functions(eager, model_data, batch_strategy)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/utils/tensorflow/models.py", line 481, in _get_tf_train_functions
self._get_tf_call_model_function(
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/utils/tensorflow/models.py", line 464, in _get_tf_call_model_function
tf_call_model_function(next(iter(init_dataset)))
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 780, in **call**
result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 823, in _call
self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 696, in _initialize
self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 2855, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3213, in _maybe_define_function
graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3065, in _create_graph_function
func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 986, in func_graph_from_py_func
func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 600, in wrapped_fn
return weak_wrapped_fn().**wrapped**(*args, **kwds)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 962, in wrapper
return autograph.converted_call(
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 591, in converted_call
return _fall_back_unconverted(f, args, kwargs, options, e)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 398, in _fall_back_unconverted
return _call_unconverted(f, args, kwargs, options)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 339, in _call_unconverted
return f(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/utils/tensorflow/models.py", line 293, in train_on_batch
prediction_loss = self.batch_loss(batch_in)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/nlu/classifiers/diet_classifier.py", line 1417, in batch_loss
sequence_lengths = self._get_sequence_lengths(
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/utils/tensorflow/models.py", line 1112, in _get_sequence_lengths
sequence_lengths = tf.ones([batch_dim], dtype=tf.int32)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py", line 201, in wrapper
return target(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 3041, in ones
output = _constant_if_small(one, shape, dtype, name)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 2732, in _constant_if_small
if np.prod(shape) < 1000:
File "<**array_function** internals>", line 5, in prod
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 3030, in prod
return _wrapreduction(a, np.multiply, 'prod', axis, dtype, out,
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 87, in _wrapreduction
return ufunc.reduce(obj, axis, dtype, out, **passkwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 845, in **array**
raise NotImplementedError(
NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (strided_slice_6:0) to a numpy array. This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a Tensor to a NumPy call, which is not supported

Rasa Version     : 2.2.9
Rasa SDK Version : 2.2.0
Rasa X Version   : None
Python Version   : 3.8.7
Operating System : macOS-10.15.7-x86_64-i386-64bit
Python Path      : /usr/local/bin/python3.8

Answer (score 0):

this should be fixed in 2.2.10, which was released today: https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa/releases/tag/2.2.10